# Why does C use modulus for random numbers?

Tags: c, random, numbers

C:

```
rand() % (max - min)
```

Let's say the random is between 0-10..

```
rand() % 10
```

`0.567 % 10` = that same number. (0.567). It isn't really doing anything. a `rand()` is always between 0-1, and as long as max-min is always >= 1, it will do nothing at all.

Wouldn't you just use multiplication instead of modulo?

```
int rand = rand() * (max - min) + 1
```

Comment: *rand() is always between 0-1* - this is not correct for C.

Answer (score 5):

`rand()` returns a number between `0` and `RAND_MAX`. You would then use modulo to constrain it to a certain range. So if you wanted a number between 0 and 10, you would do `rand() % 10`.

Comment: Oh.. Maybe I'm mixing up my languages.. I thought rand() was a number between 0 and 1.

Comment: @thisguy I think you're thinking of Java.